# saving a text file as RData and import it in R

Tags: r

SNP filtering for missing and redundant markers

I split a large text file (30 GB in size) to small 40 files in the cluster and saved it as RData. Then I am importing these small RData files to R to filter these for missing and redundant SNP markers. But it is giving an error.

I want to split large files to small files, save them as RData, import to R and filtering for missing and redundant markers.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I would do this in Plink; you may not have to split up the files to do these quality control steps.

Answer (score 0):

RData file is a binary file and your splited files are tab separated text file. So, they cannot be load with `load()`. I will suggest removing all header information and column names before you split the vcf file. And load the files into r with `read.table(sep='\t')`. Hope the above can help.

I don't have any idea about how to save text file to RData file outside r environment. But, if you concern the big file size of your vcf file and you want to filter the data before loading, I suggest using `read_tsv_chunked` which can load every chunk (`chunk_size =`) of data and do some process on each chunk of data, and finally available in r environment. And beware of `skip` the number of header line before column names. The following are the script.

```
library(tidyverse)

filterFun <- function(df, pos) {
  df <- unique(df)
  count.nas <- rowSums(is.na(df))
  df[-which(count.nas>(0.05*ncol(df))),]
}

data <- read_tsv_chunked("xxx.vcf", skip = 22, chunk_size = 10000, callback = DataFrameCallback$new(filterFun))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to save the text file as an RData file.

Comment: Hi Jessica. I edit the answer and add some code. See if the code can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Can you share how to save the text file as an RData file in R environment?

Comment: Hi @Jessica. You have to create or load somethings into R environment and use `save.image("filename.RData)` to save all objects in the environment. Or use `save(list = c("object name", ...), file = "filename.RData")` to selectively save objects that you want.